# Find the permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form

> Let:
>
> $$J=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda&1&0\\ 0&\lambda&1\\ 0&0&\lambda
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find a permutation matrix $M$ such that $$M J M^{-1} = J^{t}$$

I know that $J$ is a Jordan form matrix, but I don't even have an idea as to how to approach the problem.

Comment: I presume you mean let $J = $ that matrix.

Comment: Forget $M$ for the moment. Can you come up with a sequence of row and column swaps that transpose $J$?

Comment: Oh, forgot about that, thanks for notyfing me !

Comment: @amd I can come up with such sequence but does that help in any way in finding the matrix M ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be standard basis. Then $J.e_1=\lambda e_1$, $J.e_2=e_1+\lambda e_2$, and $J.e_3=e_2+\lambda e_3$. In other words, $J.e_3=\lambda e_3+e_2$, $J.e_2=\lambda e_2+e_1$, and $J.e_1=e_1$.  So, consider the permutation

- $e_1\rightarrow e_3$
- $e_2\rightarrow e_2$;
- $e_3\rightarrow e_1$.

The matrix of the linear map $v\mapsto J.v$ with respect to the basis which consists of $e_3$, $e_2$, and $e_1$ is then$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\1&\lambda&0\\0&1&\lambda\end{bmatrix}=J^T.$$So, let $M$ be the inverse of the change-of-bases matrix between $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $\{e_3,e_2,e_1\}$, which is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Then you will have $MJM^{-1}=J^t$.

Comment: I dont quite get the reasoning behind this solution, I see that I need to solve the equation: $MJ=J^{t}M$ but i dont know ho to proceed now

Comment: No, you certainly *don't* need to solve that equation, since what I did *proves* that $MJM^{-1}=J^T$.

Comment: Still why do you considered said permutation, I sitll dont see the reasoning behind this

Comment: Do you agree that $J.e_1=\lambda e_1$?

Comment: Yes but i dont see how multiplying by the standart basis helps in any way

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of “multiplying by the standart basis”. But, if you agree that $J.e_1=\lambda e_1$, then I suppose that you agree that if $B$ is a basis whose third vector is $e_1$, then the entries of the third column of the matrix of the linear map $v\mapsto J.v$ with respect to that basis will be $0$, $0$, and $\lambda$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you're right, but aren't you forgetting about the matrix $M^{-1}$? I would appreciate if you wrote the entire line of thinking instead of posting numerous short comments on the post

Comment: I've done it. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

There are only five permutation matrices to try.

I found $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ works, by trial and error.  (I checked $MJ\stackrel{?}=J^tM$.)